# How to set any value on AccessDecisionManager Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring security and ldap for auth. I have decide method of  AccessDecisionManager

```
public class CustomAccessDecisionManager extends AbstractAccessDecisionManager  {

    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object filter,Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes){

    //I want to set specific value for 
    //each user here and want to get at controller 
}
```

I want to set some value in decide() method and use this value in controller . I want to set some spring config context or other value for each user here . Can any one guide me how can it possible . Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can set the value to `authentication`, and set `authentication` into `SecurityContextHolder`, after that, you can get the `authentication` from `SecurityContextHolder` in your controller.

Comment: @chaoluo as i see i can only set authentication value Boolean . But i need set any string values here and want to read on controller . As  authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);  can you suggest me how it is possible

Comment: `authentication` implements `Authentication`, e.g `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, `OpenIDAuthenticationToken`, you need to cast `Authentication` to your own class,  I think you can set the value to `detail` of `Authentication`

Comment: @chaoluo i used UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and now comes access denies

Comment: @chaoluo thanks i have done it . First need create object with constructor and set values , not using setter .

Comment: You can `getDetails` and `setDetails` , then set into ContextHolder, why create a new one ? that maybe miss something in your `Authentication`